# Can I find if part of a cookie's value exists with PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I understand I can check if a cookie exists:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookievalue'])){ 
Do stuff
}
```

Can I check if part of a value exists in any of the cookies that have already been set?

so for example the values below are set in separate cookies:

**john865123**

**andrew0987**

**tim12**

**jam865es**

Can I do a check to see IF the value '865' exists in any of the cookies?

thanks.

Comment: cookie values are just strings. use normal string operations...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.. by making use of a case-insensitive [`stripos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['this_is_a_cookie'])){
    if(stripos($_COOKIE['this_is_a_cookie'],'this_is_a')!==false)
    {
        echo "Exists !!!";
    }
}
```

**`EDIT :`**

> Can I do a check to see IF the value '865' exists in any of the
> cookies?

A simple `foreach` construct to loop through the cookies..

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $ck => $cv)
{
      if(stripos($cv,'867')!==false)
    {
        echo "Exists !!!";
        break;
    }
}
```